# Extract EXIF orientation from JPEG without using any libraries

Tags: java, image, jpeg, exif

I need to extract orientation from EXIF data in a JPEG file but I can't use external libraries like [metadata-extractor](http://www.drewnoakes.com/code/exif/).
Is it possible?

Comment: Using external libraries is all modern software development is about ... But if you are really not allowed to use external jars (for whatever reason) you can always "borrow" the code from the mentioned library, it's open source after all ;-)

Comment: *"I can't use external libraries"*  Why not?

Answer (score 2):

The library you have mentioned includes a lot of work. If you cannot use it then you will have to do the bunch of work yourself.

Short answer: yes, it's possible, but I would suggest you use a third-party library like the one you mentioned.